# Can a Canadian volunteer in the US without applying for a work visa? If so, what documents are needed?

Tags: usa, paperwork, canadian-citizens, volunteering

I would like to volunteer at the Emerald City comic convention in Seattle.  What documentation do I need to cross the US border? I am Canadian.

Comment: Related:  [Is volunteer work allowed in the US while visiting under the VWP?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47943/is-volunteer-work-allowed-in-the-us-while-visting-under-the-vwp)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert that one talks about B1/B2, VWP but Canadians need neither... but the advice in general looks good.

Comment: Since you can volunteer under the normal terms of visiting the US I don't think they would need anything extra.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of any question about the Visa Waiver Program, since Canadian citizens do not need a visa (or, therefore, a visa waiver) to enter the US.

Comment: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/619/~/visiting-the-u.s.---documents-required-for-canadian-citizens-%2F-residents-%2F Traveling from Canada to the USA requires a passport

Comment: @DavidRicherby but the allowed activities under the VWP and in B visitor status are the same. Canadians who enter as visitors are in B status even though they don't require B visas.

Comment: @chx even though Canadians don't need a B visa, they are admitted when coming as "visitors for business or pleasure" in B status, with the same restrictions on allowed activities.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61860/can-short-term-visitors-do-charity-volunteer-work is itself a duplicate

Comment: I have retracted my close vote as a duplicate, since this question is not a valid one. (This specific 'job' is not volunteering.)

Answer (score 3):

There are no "volunteers" at the Emerald City Comic Con (ECCC). The people you think of as volunteers, are known as ECCC Minions, and they are [paid minimum wage](http://www.emeraldcitycomicon.com/About/ECCC-Minions/) for the hours they work, as well as given free entrance to the Convention during hours they do not.

You would most likely not be legal using a tourist visa, or the VWP. You might try contacting [ReedPOP](http://www.reedpop.com/), the company that runs the ECCC (among many others) using [their contact form.](http://www.reedpop.com/Contact-Us/)