# Is it allowed to volunteer for a nonprofit hostel (501c) in exchange for lodging under a B1/B2/VWP visa in the United States?

Tags: usa, tourist-visas, volunteering

Duties are generally helping new guests, preparing new rooms and similar duties. It is a voluntary service program. I will not get any compensation except the lodging in exchange for volunteering. Would it be legal to volunteer for a 501c nonprofit hostel under the tourist visa in the US?

Comment: One thing to consider is whether the hostel requires a background check. If there's any work with children, an organization may want a **criminal** background check.

Comment: Hi Kate; I have already seen the post, thanks. I’m unsure if Hostelling International is a permitted organisation under the law since they charge hostel fees and may not be a charity like others. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It may be that receiving payment "in kind" (lodging) is considered to be working for pay.

Comment: Even if it is a nonprofit? And it is voluntary work.

Comment: [This page](https://www.immihelp.com/can-you-do-volunteer-work-in-the-us-on-a-tourist-visa/) states: *Your work shouldn’t offer any reward or compensation, neither in the present nor in the future*. Another possible SE duplicate is [On what visa is it legal to work for a bed/food in the USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73296/on-what-visa-is-it-legal-to-work-for-a-bed-food-in-the-usa?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @user19424 It's not voluntary work as you state "in exchange for volunteering" - this means you're getting paid for it, to the value of the lodging.

Comment: Ask yourself: if you didn't 'volunteer' to do this work in exchange for lodging, would the hostel likely be paying someone to do it? If the answer even *might* be yes, then you can pretty much guarantee that it's not allowed under a tourist visa. Whether or not the organization is a non-profit is irrelevant.