# What visa does an Australian need to complete an unpaid internship in New York?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, study, australian-citizens

I am struggling to work out the appropriate visa to apply for. 
My situation is as follows:

- I am an Australian citizen.
- I am currently completing my Masters of Social work in Australia as a full-time student.
- A compulsory part of the degree is a 500 hour (over 3 months) unpaid 
  placement within an organisation.
- I am planning to complete this in New York with a non-profit organisation that has indicated their willingness to take me on for 500 hours as required by my Australian university.

What is the correct visa to apply for as I will not be engaged with 
any American university (student visa) nor will I be a paid worker of the 
organisation (working visa)?

Comment: What is your citizenship?  Also, as far as "roughly 3 months", an important question may be whether it's more or less than 90 days.

Comment: Finally, is the organization a charity or other nonprofit?

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/getting-us-visa-b-1-do-volunteer-work.html

Comment: Hi @NateEldredge thanks for your q's. It will definitely be for longer than 3 months, I am Australian and it is with a non-profit

Comment: Is the "non-profit" organization a US corporation, or is it an international organization (such as a UN department or agency)?

Comment: It is a US corporation I think: Association to Benefit Children - 
Nonprofit or community organization  http://www.a-b-c.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you want to stay as a visitor in the United States over 90 days you need a B1/B2 visa.
2. The volunteer situation is well described in [Is volunteer work allowed in the US while visiting under the VWP or a B1/B2 visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47943/is-volunteer-work-allowed-in-the-us-while-visting-under-the-vwp) (VWP or B1/B2 is the same):

> The most significant restriction is that you can only volunteer to do things that are normally done on a voluntary basis, i.e. without pay.
>
> You also can't do "anything that would benefit a commercial enterprise", and there are restrictions on things like unpaid internships. However assuming that the Planetary Society of Pasadena is a not-for-profit you should be fine.

See links at that answer.

In my opinion, and understand that I am not an USCIS officer and I do not even play one on TV, you have a pretty solid case to get this visa if

1. you can provide credible proof you have enough funds for a stay in New York this long. At least $20 a night for accommodation (expect to live in a cupboard under the stairs) and at least $10 to eat a day (hope you like ramen, anything better will be rare at $10). A more realistic number is $50 a day, at least. So 3000 or rather 5000 USD at 100 days.
2. the organization provides a letter, preferably notarized, stating their intent towards your placement and their non-profit status.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is much appreciated. Where did you get the highlighted text from? I am not sure whether I fully fit the category of only doing work that is usually unpaid, but it will be for a not for profit..

Comment: I got it from the answer linked.

Answer (score 4):

Your purpose may fit under a [J-1 visa](https://j1visa.state.gov/basics/):

> The J-1 Visa provides countless opportunities for international
>   candidates looking to travel and gain experience in the United States.
>   The multifaceted programs enable foreign nationals to come to the U.S.
>   to teach, study, conduct research, demonstrate special skills or
>   receive on the job training for periods ranging from a few weeks to
>   several years.

because you're undergoing training as part of your degree.

The problem is that the program requires a sponsor who works with various employers and companies to place people. You might take a look at agencies local to your proposed organization, contact them and see if the sponsor would be able to get the employer certified to host a j-1 person. For instance, there's an [American Australian Association](http://www.americanaustralian.org/?j1worktravelfaqs) in New York City. They even say that you don't have to have job when you arrive in the US. It would be more expensive than a B-1/B-2: US$840.

Comment: Thanks! I contacted the AAA and they advised: "Thank you for your email - we cannot help in your circumstances since all work done with the J1 visa has to be paid the minimum wage."